# Is it possible to test for quota errors when using Gmail api?

Tags: php, gmail-api

I've built an application that will scan users' email for questions and generate statistics.  It's quite possible this will hit the quota limits, so I want to handle that situation.

I know the documentation says a query will return a JSON error package, but the documentation doesn't provide any insight as to how that will manifest itself if I'm using Google's PHP library.  Will an exception be thrown?  Will the expected objects I get back be a stdClass object instead? The documentation is sorely lacking as usual.

I'd love to just give it a try and figure out what happens, but unfortunately I can't lower my quota limits to 1 to ensure I get an error.  Is there some way to spoof an error?

Comment: Got a link to SDK? Not sure which it is. Can look at the code. With their other APIs you get real granular with quotas (thinking geo / maps). Have you explored GPC API console section for options on lowering quotas / setting caps?

Comment: @ficuscr: PHP Lib: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/. Quotas: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota.  Changing quotas involves sending a manual request to Google.  Nothing automatic.

Comment: TIAS. Don't auth API with access key. Assume 'anonymous' quotas are low enough you can hit them?

Comment: FWIW my guess is you'll get one of these. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/f88a98dbaac0207e177419a15214ab4fcf30c47a/src/Google/Service/Exception.php